# What size breaker box am I going to need?

Tags: tankless

I would like to use a Smith Four chamber electric tankless water heater it requires 240 V 60 A each on two circuits. Recommended wire size is six it will be located less than 20 feet away from the breaker box. This is a new construction and I am also looking into putting in Heated floors using heated water tubes know that this will require a second source for heating. I do not have information as to draw on power that the subfloor system will need at this time. However, I do need to find the size panel breaker box for the hot water heater. Will I need will a 200 amp or do I need to move to a 225 amp breaker box to cover the draw on the tankless hot water heater AE Smith Model R4LR-280E 100. I would prefer to use square D’s QO brand which I have only found in a 200 amp box, over Homeline which comes in a 225 amp box

Comment: Why are you wanting to go electric tankless, especially with radiant floor heat in play?

Comment: It's not the panel that you need to worry about (though bigger is better) because you can add a 2nd panel. With the world pushing more electric everything, you'll probably want a 2nd panel anyway. What you need to do is ensure that your service from the power company is sufficient to supply all your electric heating, EV car charging and electric everything else. You could have a 600A capable commercial panel installed, but if you've only got a 200A service from the PoCo, you won't get more than 200A available to your house to power all your devices.

Comment: QO 225A panels are certainly available. As are QO 300A and 400A panels. Call an electrical supply, or ask your electrician as it's a new build.

Comment: Do they still make QO 300A and 400A panels? I'm not finding any residential units on the Schneider site. It also might not matter, because it's easy enough to hang two 200A panels off a 400A meter main. Might be quite expensive though.

Comment: I went to the SE site and looked for QO in sizes 225A and up - if they are showing things they don't make, I can't help that. As usual, ignore the pricing they show there, it's often way off, or for a pallet, or some such. Call a distributor for actual pricing and availability.  I certainly have the boring old 2X 200A on my CL320 https://www.se.com/us/en/product-range/7249-qo-load-centers/?N=2474617795+2319998151+1652047512+3834010662+2426213117

Comment: Got it, those didn't come up under Residential, just under All Products.

Comment: @KMJ -- >200A in QO requires going into their commercial panelboard line (the NQ)

Comment: This is a small vacation home about an hour away. I plan on being there 4-5 weeks a year. I am in my 60s and looking to retire in the next five years to this location permanently.  The tankless is to be used for showers and dishwashers and laundry. ImFor the radiant floors, I was looking for a system that would use a more conventional heating source

Answer (score 6):

A tanked water heater is superior to tankless in every way other than how much hot water you get at once. A hot water tank is a battery that you can can charge slowly (even overnight at lower rates). Every other claimed benefit over tanked is a misleading marketing fable.

If you are worried about running out of hot water, get a bigger tank. Or keep hotter water in the tank and use a mixing valve on the output to bring it down to below scalding temps.

As for a heating source on all electric look into a heatpump. That will give you a lot more heat for the electricity you put in.

Comment: gotta agree with everything  you said!

Comment: Nonsense. Tankless is better **if you can power it**.  You're not wasting energy heating a tank all day long and breeding legionella.  The problem is, it takes ***a LOT of power***, and system design is **ruthlessly unforgiving to careless people** guilty of magical thinking.  And that is why some think they suck.   That said, a *heat pump* water heater would be superior, even if tanked - as long as you can use the outdoors (or air in need of conditioning) as the ultimate heat source.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica the tank is very well insulated so the standby losses are going to be minimal, a tankless is also gonig to have standby losses because of the electronics requied to detect flow. Especially if you have different day and night rates and you only let it heat at night, and you can prevent legionella by bumping up the temperature to above 51°C/124°F.

Answer (score 2):

If you **REALLY** want to do electric tankless water heaters for both domestic hot water and space heating,   you will need to do a load calculation...big time.   My best guess would be you'd need 2 (yes **TWO**)  200 amp panels fed by a class 320 service.  A lot going on here.  The power company might not be able to service that without a major upgrade.  Personally I believe electric tankless are a poor choice. They take **A LOT OF POWER** and as the country goes more and more all electric, we can hardly keep the lights on now.  If you want tankless, if you have natural gas available, I'd go that route.  If not a tank type water heater stores heated water and are generally 30 amps.  You may need 2, one for DHW and the other for floor heating. But that's just my guess on limited information.  I always hate to say this here on a DIY site, but this really **REALLY** needs a pro to do the load calcs and specify the equipment needed. At the end of the day,  you might discover that tank type WHs that don't need such a large electrical supply might be a **lot less expensive.**  New tank type WHs are very well insulated and no less efficient than tankless.

Comment: It's described as a new build, so they just order the size service they (or their electrician) calculates, or larger.

Comment: @Ecnerwal    agreed, I saw that it was a new build. But here goes:  Susan wants electric tankless for both DHW and space heating, She specified they would each need 2 60 amp supplies presumably at 240v.    That right there is 240 amps at 240v.    WOW!  then add in electric range ,  probably a heat pump with electric aux heat, an electric dryer, maybe EV charging and of course the normal outlet and lighting circuits and WOW!  She'd need to install a cable directly to a nuclear electric plant (LOL)     A class 320 would be the minimum IMHO, or maybe a true 400 amp service with CT  metering.

Comment: And I'm sure the local PoCo would _love_ to sell the install for a 320 or 400A service and make the profit off of the power being sucked down by all those devices! Don't think Ecnerwal was questioning your math, George, just that it's a new build so they'll drop whatever is ordered. Unless, of course, they're already oversubscribed and simply can't provide it. _ahem... California..._

Comment: @FreeMan  I didn't mean to come across with any criticism of ecernwal ....just say that "pre-instillation planning is needed here.   This isn't just a case of some lighting ( which nowadays is VERY efficient) and convenience circuits with a house that has a gas fired WH, range, HP for space heating or even just a gas furnace .  If so electrical requirements would be relatively small.   But with the proposed loading, man you gotta get it right the first time, fixing it later would very costly.

Comment: Didn't think it was a criticism, just that you seemed to be defending your calculations which nobody had challenged. I agree with you 100%. This house is gonna suck electricity like it's going out of style. Makes me wonder where all that juice is going to come from...

Comment: I am looking at the tankless for showers, dishwashing and laundry. This is a little vacation house that I am using to downsize for a retirement home in the next five years the heating system for the floor I’m looking at more conventional heat sources and actually like what I’m hearing about the heat pump. A tent heater would have to be drained and reheated. Every time I come back and with the scale in the water. I am concerned about sediment building up in a tanked heater.

Answer (score 2):

SMH everybody's hatin' on tankless.

That's not fair. Tankless works fine and is actually more efficient and takes less total power. The problem is **tankless is ruthlessly unforgiving to foolish optimists** - and they get in trouble by undersizing the tankless for the task *because they're worried about their service size*.  Tankless takes **a WHOLE lot of power** and that generally means no, it's not going to happen on your existing service size.  If you're willing to provision the power, tankless is fantastic.

And even better - tankless can be done right at the point of use. You can slap a 50A tankless right behind a shower, stick a low-flow showerhead on there and you not only have tankless, you have *instant* tankless since the water pipe is now 3 feet long.  Do that in every bathroom; maybe tap the sink hot water off the shower unit.  *The British have package units called "Electric Showers" which do exactly that*.  Multiple point-of-use tankless are also *genuinely* the most efficient, since they do not abandon hot water in long pipes at the end of the shower or use.

Now if you try to have this "instant hot water" conversation with these tankers, they'll trot out recirculation systems - which are an efficiency disaster, and can even scald you.  Mind you they just got done claiming that tanked is just as efficient as tankless. They should be done with a 3rd pipe strictly for recirculation, but most simply shove the tepid hot water back onto the cold line, which sets the stage for scalding, since modern thermostatic mixing faucets add cold to hot that would scald you.

"Just don't keep your tank at scalding" say the tankers, except now you're breeding legionella and other bacteria.  Don't worry, they'll say they look at their water all the time and never saw any bacteria :)

### That power problem, though.

My rule of thumb is "40 amps per GPM you want", maybe a bit less in the hot south.  Grab a bucket and a stopwatch.  You can also add low-flow showerheads or low-flow spigots to this conversation.

This brings you to a rather sobering ampere number. And this, unfortunately, is where those foolish optimists with their "magical thinking" believe they can make major compromises and it will just work out in the end.  Maybe in summer.  But real world, here's how that fails: **The water goes tepid**.  I mean the heater is giving its all - water is just moving too fast, it's not exposed to the heater long enough to heat it fully before new water comes up. **And *paradoxically*, the way you fix that is to reduce flow, which is NOT intuitive to the person in the shower**. The problem is, there's usually a long pipe of water involved, so there's a long time lag between "trying something" and "experiencing the effect" - thus cause/effect seems to break down.  **This misery is always blamed on the tankless heater** even though the fault lies with the fool who sized it... and the result is political pressure from other household members to **abandon tankless and go back to tanked**.  And that's where many tankless dreams die.  It ain't the tankless, it's the fools.

So yeah. Provision that 400A service and go to town with tankless. *Did that sound anti-tankless?*   Sorry, but being realistic is better than being unrealistic **and failing**.

> Smith Four chamber electric tankless water heater it requires 240 V 60 A each on two circuits

I would expect/plan on 3 GPM (mixed) from that tankless. That's assuming 70F rise in the water and you can do the math.*  Does that sound like a whole house?  Not to me, unless the house is quite small, or carefully engineered for ultra-low-flow and the occupants are educated.

### But heat pumps change *everything*

And they pretty much create a "win" for central tanked heaters.  Heat pumps don't make heat from electricity, they use much less electricity to *simply move* existing heat from other places, like outdoors.  And if you don't think there's heat outdoors, look up Kelvin and absolute zero.

In this case you're using 1 watt of power to get 3-6 watts of heat. (sometimes as low as 1-2 watts but you always beat unity, at least this side of Yavoriv, Russia).  The only gotcha is that the cheapest heat pump water heaters steal heat from inside your utility room.  So your furnace has more work to do, and/or you get free air conditioning, depending on how you look at it :) Better units are a head on a split heat pump system and have an outdoor unit.

But back to tankless.

### The Load Calculation must be considered

Simply piling things onto an electrical service is not allowed.  The limits of a service are defined by a **NEC Article 220 Load Calculation** and most houses find it advantageous to use the alternate method in NEC 220.82, or a worksheet provided by the municipality.  Note that tankless heater don't get the "discount" since it's a big surge load that comes on all at once. Neither does EV charging.

The Load Calculation is intended to be used by tallying all your loads and then picking the service size sufficient for them all.  In practicality we generally end up picking the loads based on the service size that you've got.

There is some [magic from the future (read: 1990 microcontroller tech *finally* turned into usable products)](https://youtu.be/CVLLNjSLJTQ?t=450) to dynamically interrupt other loads to keep service loads within limits.  That can help make a Load Calculation work that would otherwise not.

However, all of this bodes ill for a 120A tankless heater, unless the house is all-gas otherwise.

> Will I need will a 200 amp or do I need to move to a 225 amp breaker box to cover the draw

No, provisioning doesn't work that way. You can't enlarge the breaker panel without upgrading the wires and having a conversation with your power company about your usage.  More likely than not, the quest for a tankless will call for a big bump up to 400A service (the power company calls it "Class 320"; their amp is our 1.25 amp for reasons).

However, 400A would be good news in two ways. First, it physically implemented as two 200A panels, and you already have one finished and ready to go!  Second, having a whole second 200A leaves you free to go with a larger tankless that may be more practical.

> I would prefer to use square D’s QO brand which I have only found in a 200 amp box, over Homeline which comes in a 225 amp box

Nobody overpays for QO unless they care about quality. If quality is what you want, QO goes much larger (it is an industrial line, after all) or you can go Eaton CH, or Siemens PL series, which are competitor pro brands.

HOMeline is, well, truth in advertising lol, it's their cheapie line.  Of course if you're shopping at big-box **home** stores, which cater to the cheap -- they'll tend to feature HOM's entire line but not really bother showing the higher-end QO stuff.  Talk to a real electrical supply.

---

---

*

- 1 BTU is defined as the energy needed to heat 1 pound of water 1 degree F.   So if you have 1 pound (pint) of water and want 70 degree F rise, that'll take 70 BTU.
- Water heaters are 240V, so 240 watts per amp.
- 1 watt provides 3.41 BTUs per hour.
- 1 GPM flow rate equates to 500 pounds of water per hour.
- Example: 1 GPM / 500 pounds per hour of water, at 70 degree F rise, needs 35,000 BTU/hour.